# Keep prefix even if dropSpecialCharacters is true with ngx-mask

Tags: html, angular, ngx-mask

```
<input matInput prefix="+55" mask=" (00) 00000-0000" [dropSpecialCharacters]="true" type="text" formControlName="phone" name="phone">
```

With this code I'm already getting a value masked as `+55 (11) 12345-6789`, and in the form a value like `11123456789`, but I need to keep the prefix on value like `+5511123456789`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way to do that but you can just re-add the prefix in your submit function.